# Pycharm: Leave Single Comment Line Untouched During Reformatting

Tags: python, pycharm

In Pycharm, I have the following python code:

```
...
for index, row in df.iterrows():
# here comes some logic
    print(   index)
...
```

I perform a reformatting of it (via: `Menu - Code - Reformat Code`).

Afterwards, the code looks like this:

```
...
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # here comes some logic
    print(index)
...
```

I would like to have the comment line unindented:

```
...
for index, row in df.iterrows():
# here comes some logic
    print(index)
...
```

What do I have to do that the reformatting does not indent the comment line?

(working with `//formatter:off` etc. is not an option)

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? It violates [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments)

Comment: Although PEP8 suggests it differently, for me an unindented comment _explains_ the code. I use an indented comment just for _inactive_ code (that was commented out)